# copy cells to different worksheet based on worksheet name

Tags: excel, vba

I have been looking around and i cant seem to find the same flavor of question that I have 
lets say I have a worksheet that has two columns of data one column I apply a filter too and then use that to create worksheets. I want then to paste the values from the second column that to a matching worksheet

So if I had column a had values a b c c d

and column b had values name fluid id state county 
 I want the code to look at name and paste it to the proper worksheet in this example it would be worksheet a for fluid it would be worksheet b and so on and so forth

i am thinking its a for each formula and then loop it so

```
Sub C2s()
Dim contr As Control
Dim RN As Range
Dim LR As Integer

LR = Sheet3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
RN = Sheet3.Range("B1:B" & LR)

For Each Cell In RN
    If 

    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Without writing the actual code, pretty much "yes", loop through your filtered values and inside your loop use a Select Case value option, to do the different action you want for each value

Comment: how do i reference the worksheet name and copy the adjacent cell.                                       'For Each Cell In Rn Select Case case Is ="Sheet name" copy adjacent cell to proper worksheeet' that the part i cant seem to get

Answer (score 0):

** Edited to fix column range being allocated

This is untested, but should give you the idea of how to loop and use the offset column to process your values.  The SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) means it will only process the filtered records in your selection

```
    Dim MyCell As Range, 
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim WorksheetToCopyTo as string 
Dim LR As Integer

LR = Sheet3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set MyRange = Sheet3.Range("A1:A" & LR)

For Each MyCell In MyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    WorksheetToCopyTo = MyCell.offset(0,1)
    Select Case WorksheetToCopyTo
        Case "Fluid"
            <do something here>
        Case "County"
            <do something here>
    End Select
Next MyCell
```